How Can i Store Id & Password securly outside of kivymd app folder
I want to store id , password outside of app folder securly because i usually store it inside a jsonstore inside app folder & everytime i update the app from playstore all the stored files are gone and i have to re-login again.
i've tried stroing outside im totally new and couldnt think a workaround

Updaating an App should not remove your private files. See this {question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231170/are-internal-storage-files-deleted-on-app-update#:~:text=An%20upgrade%20will%20not%20remove%20internal%20files%20--,You%20will%20need%20to%20add%20an%20additional%20check.).

@JohnAnderson Hi, do you think its same for the kivy/kivymd too like other framework?
But  every time i update app my json files are totally removed
i have Json folder in main.py file directory

@JohnAnderson Hi, can you please please help me with the idea of how to save id and passwords in a json file and save it securely and it wont be removed when i update app through playstore. Please.
